# How to call AIDL services on app startup

Tags: java, android, aidl

My app is called **MyNiceApp**. MyNiceApp is mostly just a core that loads a **CORE** view which gets populated by other plugins which the user downloads as wishes. I define the various areas on the core view that can be populated by the plugins via Interfaces in MyNiceApp. How can I load apps that implement these interfaces via AIDL when the app starts?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

Any other approach that could help achieve this functionality would suffice. It does't have to be only implementable via AIDL only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `bindService()`, using an explicit `Intent` that identifies the plugin's exported service.

To identify what plugins exist, use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentServices()` to find all apps that have a service with some `<intent-filter>` tied to your app. Confirm that the apps implementing the matches are who they say they are, via signature checks. Then, you can use the `ResolveInfo` from `queryIntentServices()` to construct the explicit `Intent` for binding.

[This pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/SigCheck) demonstrates the basic process. In my case, I am expecting exactly one match, whereas you perhaps are expecting N matches.